# Oracle SQL : Why cant each foreign key from separate tables reference to a single primary key?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
create table Product(
      Prodid number(5) primary key
    , Prodesc varchar(20)
    , Price number(6,2)
    , Stock number (6)
);
```

This foreign key refers to a prodid of product table:

```
create table Purchase(
      Purid number(9) primary key
    , Proid number(5)
    , CONSTRAINT fk_Product FOREIGN KEY(Proid) REFERENCES Product(Prodid)
    , qty number(6)
    , supname char(15)
);
```

This foreign key also refers to a prodid of product table:

```
create table Sales(
      Saleid number(9) primary key
    , Proid number(5)
    , CONSTRAINT fk_Product FOREIGN KEY(Proid) REFERENCES Product(Proid)
    , qty number(6)
    , custname char(15)
);
```

But I am getting an error. "name already used by a constraint." . Any solution to overcome this?. I want those two table's(Purchase & Sales) foreign key reference to the same primary key of Product table.

Comment: Well, just name the other FK something else.  The name of the FK has nothing to do with the references defined for it.

Comment: That also does'n work.

Comment: See this example:                                                 SQL> create table a(r number(10) primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table b(s number(10) , CONSTRAINT fk_a FOREIGN KEY      (s) REFERENCES a(
r));

Table created.

SQL> create table c(t number(10) , CONSTRAINT fk_a FOREIGN KEY (t) REFERENCES a(
r));
create table c(t number(10) , CONSTRAINT fk_a FOREIGN KEY (t) REFERENCES a(r))
                                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint

Comment: ... the error message states precisely what is wrong, no?

Comment: So how can the changes be made?

Comment: You should use 3 different constraint names, like `fk_a1`, `fk_a2`, `fk_a3`. You Appear to believe that the naming of fk constraints must follow a generis rule. This would be a misconception.

Comment: How can I reference those foreign keys to tht same primary key?

Comment: You should use 2 different constraint names, like fk_a, fk_b instead of naming both "fk_Product" for Purchase and Sales–  collapsar Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as @OldProgrammer and others suggest is that you're trying to use the same constraint name in both cases.  You'd need to use different constraint names.  You'll probably want to use some sort of naming convention for your keys-- I prefer one that uses both the parent and the child in the name.  So I'd do something like

```
create table Purchase(
      Purid number(9) primary key
    , Proid number(5)
    , CONSTRAINT fk_purchase_product FOREIGN KEY(Proid) REFERENCES Product(Prodid)
    , qty number(6)
    , supname char(15)
);

create table Sales(
      Saleid number(9) primary key
    , Proid number(5)
    , CONSTRAINT fk_sales_product FOREIGN KEY(Proid) REFERENCES Product(Proid)
    , qty number(6)
    , custname char(15)
);
```

Not related to your error but I would be highly dubious that any column should ever be declared as a `char(15)`.  `varchar2(15)` almost certainly makes more sense-- it is highly unlikely that you want your names space padded to 15 bytes or that you want to potentially use `char` comparison semantics in your code.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Justin Cave